# Optimizing a merge sort function in python

Tags: python

Any ideas to optimize this merge sort function?

The input is a list like this: [[(1,'i'),(3,'i'),(5,'i'),(8,'i')], [(2,'n')], [(4,'t'),(7,'t')], [(6,'a')], [(9,'v')],[(10,'e')]], and output is the word: "initiative"

```
def merge(decks):
    while len(decks) > 1:
        del1 = decks.pop(0)
        del2 = decks.pop(0)
        total = list()
        while (len(del1) and len(del2)) > 0:
            if del1[0] < del2[0]:
                total.append(del1.pop(0))
            else:
                total.append(del2.pop(0))
        total.extend(del1)
        total.extend(del2)
        decks.append(total)

    word = ""
    for kort in decks[0]:
        word += kort[1]
    return word
```

Comment: `(len(del1) and len(del2)) > 0` works by sheer luck BTW :)

Comment: you could perform some small optimizations, but this is more on-topic for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that your question is off-topic for this site. The site I linked to is dedicated to this kind of questions.

Comment: I meant the first comment @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: you're anding the resuts of `len`... I would just do `if del1 and del2`, cleaner, more pythonic (since len cannot be < 0)

Answer (score 0):

There's one optimization I can think of: Reverse both `del[0]` and `del[1]` before the inner loop and change `list.pop(0)` ([an O(n) operation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)) to `list.pop()` (which is in O(1)). Reversing is also O(n), but since you do the `pop(0)`ing inside the loop, it's actually `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Why should `pop(0)` have `O(n)` and `pop()` not? The C-implementation of pop contains no loops

Comment: The `list.pop` method is indeed `O(n)` when popping from the front (with `pop(0)`). That's because it needs to move ever it removed after the popped value has been removed. That happens in [`list_ass_slice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/631fdee6e61b4ba8ce800f827fecdd536bfb04f3/Objects/listobject.c#L580), which is called by the `pop` implementation. That function has a few loops, but what we care about in particular is the call to `memmove` on line 654, which copies all the values in the list up one space. It is probably well optimized by the compiler, but it's still `O(n)`.

Comment: See [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on the Python wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Far simpler is to simply flatten the list, then sort the tuples naturally.

```
from itertools import chain, imap
from operator import itemgetter 

def merge(decks):
    return "".join(imap(itemgetter(1),
                   sorted(chain.from_iterable(decks)))
```

- `from_iterable` flattens the nested list
- `sorted` sorts the tuples in the flattened sequence naturally, by the integer first element of each tuple
- `itemgetter(1)` is an efficient implementation of `lambda x: x[1]`
- `imap` applies the access function to the list returned by `sorted`, extracting the letters
- `"".join` builds a new string from the extracted letters

Slightly less "functional" in style would be to use a list comprehension, which makes sense because `sorted` returns a list anyway, instead of a more general iterator.

```
def merge(decks):
    return "".join(x[1]
                   for x in sorted(chain.from_iterable(decks)))
```

You could also use the `heapq` module's `merge` function, which takes advantage of the fact that each nested list is already sorted, rather than simply sorting the flattened list.

```
import heapq
def merge(decks):
    return "".join(x[1] for x in heapq.merge(*decks))
```